# Is there any way to use some sort of Excel/Word code so the formula takes the data from the current row it is in?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-word

I am making a sales quote template and I have worked out a formula to work out the total based on quantity, unit price, minus any added discount in %. But the formula needs the row number added to it. Is there anything I can replace the row number with so that the formula knows how to get the values from the current row it is in?

The formula I have is as follows: =B2(D2(1-E2))

The formula I'd like is for the row number to be automatically derived from whatever row the formula cell is in. So it can be copied down the whole 'Value' column and even if rows are deleted, it won't affect each row's 'Value' field.

[image: Quote layout screenshot]

I tied using the '$' sign as I saw that mentioned in a few online posts, but it didnt work. I've tried searching Google, but it keeps bringing up information relating to other things as I think my search query has too many general excel terms in it.

Comment: What you have will already do what you want

Comment: In your formula, you need to put the `$` in the row only because you are extended down the cell in the Value column. You can use this in `F2`: `=B$2(D$2(1-E$2))`, you can put it before the letters too, but it is not really necessary for your case. This should work. Did you try this in Excel?

Comment: Using INDEX and ROW keeps referencing correct also after deleting rows/cells. Instead of `B2` you can use `INDEX(B:B,row())` where `ROW` references the current row.

Comment: These don't seem to be working once I bring the table into MS Word.

P.b - I'm not sure I get what you mean? Do you mean use ROW like this: =Brow(Drow(1-Erow))

Comment: You tagged Excel, that's how you avoid #REF error when a referenced cell is deleted. `=INDEX(B:B,ROW())` is column B in the current row.

Comment: What happens in Word depends on how you are copying/pasting your Excel table. If you paste a Link to the table and choose Excel Workshhet Object as the format, the formulas should work as in Excel if you "activate" the link. If you paste using text, rtf or html you end up with a Word table that just contains the results of the formulas, not the formulas, and Excel formulas do not work in a Word table.

Comment: I think most of the comments are missing something here.  My first concern:  I'm not aware of Excel supporting "assumed multiplication" without the `*` operator.  When I test it I get `#REF!` error.  Also, there should *not* be a `$` associated with this formula at all.  Enter this formula in F2:  `=B2*D2*(1-E2)`.  Copy/fill/drag that formula down your value column, and Excel will auto-increment the row number in each row.